# AVCaptureDevice.hasFlash returns true for front camera when no flash exists

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

Not sure what to do about this. Who do I call/what do I do to resolve this? AVFoundations programming guide has a hasFlash and is flashmode supported feature but they don't work properly. The front camera should return false but instead it returns true.

```
if flash && AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front == currentCamera.position{
            if currentCamera.hasFlash && currentCamera.isFlashModeSupported(.On){
            if let _ = try? currentCamera.lockForConfiguration() {
                currentCamera.flashMode = .On
                currentCamera.unlockForConfiguration()
                let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
                stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: process)
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like,

```
  AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
BOOL hasFlash = [device hasFlash];

if (hasFlash) {
    NSLog(@"device has a flash");
}

else{

    NSLog(@"device hasn't flash");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however I think the defaultDevice is the backCamera and hasFlash will return false (It returns false for me). It's the front camera that's the problem. hasFlash returns true for the front camera. I don't think the front camera has a flash (I think hasFlash should return false for the front camera).

Comment: show your code that how you differentiate front camera with rear?

Comment: if flash && AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front == currentCamera.position
if currentCamera.hasFlash && currentCamera.isFlashModeSupported(.on)
if let _ = try? currentCamera.lockForConfiguration() {
                    currentCamera.flashMode = .On
                    currentCamera.unlockForConfiguration()
                    let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)                 stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: process)
               }

Comment: Here's the code I'm working with. I put it in a comment and I edited the question.